# How to solve the subroutine in Augmented Lagrangian Method with L-infinity norm restriction

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

I was trying to use Augmented Lagrangian Method to a L-infinity norm restricted problem as following (where $I$ means identity matrix):

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
&\underset{x,y}{\min} &\frac12x^Tx + y^Tb\\
&\textrm{subject to} &A^Tx-Iy = 0, \|y\|_{\infty}\le\mu
\end{array}
$$
Augmented Lagrangian is as following (where $t$ should be a super parameter chosen by me):
$$L(x,y,z) = \frac12x^Tx + y^Tb + z^T(A^Tx - Iy) + \frac{t}{2}\|A^Tx -Iy \|_2^2$$
So according to the augmented lagrangian method, the iterations should be as following:
\begin{align}
(x^{(k)}, y^{(k)}) &= \arg\min_{x,y} L(x,y,z^{(k-1)}) \text{,subject to}\|y\|_{\infty}\le\mu\\
z^{(k)} &= z^{(k)} + t(A^Tx^{(k)}-Iy^{(y)})
\end{align}

My problem is that how should I deal with the subroutine of $(x^{(k)}, y^{(k)})$ under Augmented Lagrangian Method? The problem doesn't seem to have a direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Augmented Lagrangian:**

$L(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{2}x^Tx + b^Ty + i_{\|y\|_\infty \le \mu} + z^T(A^Tx-y) + \frac{\rho}{2}\|A^Tx-y\|_2^2$

For the $(x,y)$ update, I'd do a block-coordinate descent (BCD): update $x$ with $y$ held fixed and then update $y$. You might have to check that this actually convergens...

**$x$ update:** set derivative w.r.t $x$ to zero

$x^{(k+1)} = \text{argmin}_{x} L(x, y^{(k)}, z^{(k)}) = (\rho AA^T + I)^{-1}(y^{(k)}-Az^{(k)})$

**$y$ update:** complete-the-square in $y$

$$
\begin{split}
y^{(k+1)} &= \text{argmin}_{y: \|y\|_\infty \le \mu} L(x^{(k+1)}, y, z^{(k)})\\
&=\text{argmin}_{y: \|y\|_\infty \le \mu} \frac{\rho}{2}\|y - (A^Tx^{(k+1)} + (z^{(k)}-b)/\rho)\|_2^2 \\
&= \Pi_{[-\mu,\mu]^n}(A^Tx^{(k+1)} + (z^{(k)}-b)/\rho)
\end{split}
$$

**Appendix: projection onto hyper-cube**
$$\Pi_{[a_1,b_1] \times \ldots \times [a_n,b_n]}(c) = (\Pi_{[a_1,b_1]}(c_1), \ldots, \Pi_{[a_n,b_n]}(c_n)) = (\varphi(a_1, b_1, c_1),\ldots,\varphi(a_n,b_n,c_n)),$$
where $\varphi(r, s, t)$ is the projection of $t \in \mathbb R$ onto the compact interval $[r, s]$, defined by $$\varphi(r,s,t) := \begin{cases}r, &\mbox{ if}t \le r,\\t, &\mbox{ if }r < t \le s,\\s, &\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$