# Projection on convex set

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a vector $y=(y_k) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we consider the energy function
$$E:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,\; x \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_{k+1} + x_{k−1} − 2x_k)^2,$$

and the set
$$C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ s.t } |x_k − y_k| ≤ q, \forall k=1,\ldots,n\},$$
where $q$ is a fixed positive real number.

1. Show that $C$ is convex.
2. Give an explicit formula for $\pi_C(x)$, the euclidean projection of a vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$ onto $C$.

I have tried to solve this. I proved that the energy function is convex. but somehow i am getting stuck on finding the projection of the vector on set C.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE... you should know that your audience here frowns on posts like this which resemble quiz and homework questions with no evidence suggesting you've done any work on it yourself. You might want to consider editing your question to describe any attempts you've made, or more specific issues you have with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $C$ is a  product of $n$ compact intervals $[y_1 - q, y_1 + q] \times \ldots \times [y_n - q, y_n + q]$ and is therefore convex (**N.B.:** every interval is convex and the Cartesian product of a finite number of convex sets is convex)
- For computing the projection onto a hyper-cube, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2055272/168758).
- Finally, for an appropriately chosen sparse $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ (exercise), your energy can be written as $E(x) \equiv \|Ax\|_2^2$, and so your problem can be written in the form

$$\underset{x \in C}{\text{minimize }} \|Ax\|_2^2,
$$

which is solvable via a fast projected-gradient scheme like FISTA, when not solvable in closed form...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing the constructor of this quiz/hw question knows an explicit formula exists...

Comment: @dohmatob thank you so much. this was very helpful.